# How to add references parameterization to Map, BiFunction and BiConsumer in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

I have the code that works without references parameterization for Map, BiFunction and BiConsumer and this code results in Java warning.  I tried to add this parameterization but this resulted into compilation errors

```
Map numbers = new HashMap<>();
Map numbers2 = new HashMap();
numbers.put(1, "one");
numbers.put(2, "two");
numbers2.put(3, "three");
numbers2.put(4, "four");
BiFunction func = (k,v) -> v;
BiConsumer cons = (k,v) ->numbers.merge(k,v,func);
numbers2.forEach(cons);
```

Comment: You only have to add the parameterization to the maps. Then you can simply use `numbers2.forEach( (k,v) ->numbers.merge(k,v,(o,n)->n) )` and let the compiler deduce the types. But note that a merge function returning the second (new) value always, makes `numbers.merge(k,v,(o,n)->n)` behave identical to `numbers.put(k,v)`, which makes `numbers2.forEach( (k,v) ->numbers.merge(k,v,(o,n)->n) )` a complicated way of achieving the same as `numbers.putAll(numbers2)`…

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Map<Integer, String> numbers = new HashMap<>();
Map<Integer, String> numbers2 = new HashMap<>();
numbers.put(1, "one");
numbers.put(2, "two");
numbers2.put(3, "three");
numbers2.put(4, "four");
BiFunction<String, String, String> func = (v1, v2) -> v2;
BiConsumer<Integer, String> cons = (k, v) -> numbers.merge(k, v, func);
numbers2.forEach(cons);
```

I guess you where confused by `func`. `Map#merge` function accepts a function that given 2 values (old and new) produces new merged value.